# How can I use a logistic regression based on both l1 and l2 regularizations?

Tags: python

Recently I copy my codes from R to Python and I do need some help about the codes. As far as I know, the logistic regression in sklearn only includes `l1` or `l2` regularized term, which represents the lasso and ridge regression, respectively. However, implementing both l1 and l2 regularized terms,i.e., ElasticNet may be much better.

In the case of R, there is a notable package `glmnet` which can  deploy the above ideas perfectly, whereas the package `glmnet` in python seems only support Linux system instead of windows 10 in my computer (please refer to [this](https://github.com/bbalasub1/glmnet_python))
In addition, it will be much better if the package can visualize the result (such as shrinkage path)

```
#logtistic with penalty terms in sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

LogisticRegression(C=0.1,random_state=seed,penalty='l1')
LogisticRegression(C=0.1,random_state=seed,penalty='l2')
```

Comment: Well, I find sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier which seems to be the right model by implementing the loss function to be 'log' and penalty to be 'elasticnet'. So the remaining problem is the way to visualize the result (please see https://github.com/bbalasub1/glmnet_python/blob/master/test/glmnet_examples.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

```
sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='elasticnet')
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Actually, in the above answer I have found this method. I was wonder that If I could visulize the result? For example, the shrinkage path.